# ePoll not accepting some clients

Tags: c, linux, networking, epoll

I have implemented a server using epoll, in what I believe to be the standard way, in fact, when I implemented it using the example from the epoll man page I got the same behavior.

This leads me to believe that there must be a problem with my client, and that I'm making assumptions somehow where I shouldn't.  The main method of my client forks n number of clients, which then connect to the server.  What I'm seeing is that usually a subset of these clients don't trigger the epoll, and never hit the 
accept() call.  The three-way-handshake completes because there is a listening socket, so the client behaves as if it where accepted, but it never gets served, as the server doesn't know about it.  I can't figure out why this is happening, and haven't been able to find similar questions online.  Thoughts?

Here's the relevant server code:

```
// wrapper which binds to port and exits on error
listenFD = tcpSocket(host, port);
SetNonblocking(listenFD);

// wrapper which listens and exits on error
tcpListen(listenFD);

epollFD = epoll_create(EPOLL_QUEUE_LEN);
if (epollFD == -1)
    errSystem("epoll_create");

// Add the server socket to the epoll event loop
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR | EPOLLHUP | EPOLLET;
event.data.fd = listenFD;
if (epoll_ctl (epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listenFD, &event) == -1)
    errSystem("epoll_ctl");

while(TRUE){

    //struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
    numFDs = epoll_wait(epollFD, events, EPOLL_QUEUE_LEN, -1);

    for (i = 0; i < numFDs; i++){

        // Case 1: Error condition
        if (events[i].events & (EPOLLHUP | EPOLLERR)){
            errMessage("epoll: EPOLLERR");
            Close(events[i].data.fd);
            printf("Closed connection to %d\n", events[i].data.fd);
            fflush(stdout);
            continue;
        }

        // Case 2: Server is receiving a connection request
        if (events[i].data.fd == listenFD){
            // socketlen_t
            clientLen = sizeof(client);

            newFD = Accept (listenFD, (SA *)&client, &clientLen);
            SetNonblocking(newFD);
            // Set receive low water mark to message size
            SetSockOpt(newFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT, &lowWater, sizeof(lowWater));

            // Add the new socket descriptor to the epoll loop
            event.data.fd = newFD;
            event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
            if (epoll_ctl (epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, newFD, &event) == -1)
                errSystem ("epoll_ctl");

            printf("Connected to client on socket %d\n", newFD);

            // tell the client we're connected and ready 
            // (this is an attempt to fix my issue.  I'd rather not do this...)
            Writen(newFD, buffer, CLIENT_MESSAGE_SIZE);

            continue;
        }

        if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN){

            //serve the client
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the client code.  One instance of these works, but if I fork more than 5 or so (sometimes just 2) a number of them won't get accepted.

```
int Client(const char *host, const int port, const int timeLen, const int clientNum){

long double delta;
PTSTRUCTS ptstructs = (PTSTRUCTS) malloc(sizeof(TSTRUCTS));
size_t result;
stop = FALSE;

cNum = clientNum;

Signal(SIGINT, closeFD);
Signal(SIGALRM, sendMessage);

nsockets = 0;

// wrapper which calls connect() and exits with message on error
connectFD = tcpConnect(host, port);

printf("%d connected to server:\n", clientNum);
fflush(stdout);

bzero(sbuf, CLIENT_MESSAGE_SIZE);
// initialize client message
strcpy(sbuf, CLIENT_MESSAGE);


 // get the start time
getStartTime(ptstructs);
getEndTime(ptstructs);

while((delta = getTimeDelta(ptstructs)) < timeLen){

    // One or more clients blocks here for ever 
    if ((result = receiveMessage()) < CLIENT_MESSAGE_SIZE){
        break;
    }

    //sendMessage();
    alarm(1);

    //delay(USER_DELAY);
    getEndTime(ptstructs);
}

stop = TRUE;
Close (connectFD);
getEndTime(ptstructs);
delta = getTimeDelta(ptstructs);

printf("Client %d served %ld bytes in %.6Lf seconds.\n", clientNum, byteCount, delta);
fflush(stdout);

// free heap memory
free(ptstructs);
return (1);
```

}

I should probably note that I'm seeing the same behavior if I don't set EPOLLET.  I originally thought this might be the result of edge-triggering behavior, but nope.

Comment: If you close a socket, then you should probably remove it from the event set that `epoll_wait` is polling.

Comment: Good call.  Not causing this issue though...

Answer (score 0):

Does your backlog argument of listen() greater than the number of clients?

@some-programmer-dude, sorry for not commentting, the closed fd will be removed from epoll event set automatically http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html